# IBM Websphere MQ Latency for storing persistent messages Java client

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty, mq

In Websphere9 Console for "Queues", we have "Default messaging provider" and "WebSphere MQ messaging provider". One of our Q has been created with "Default messaging provider" . Now we observe some performance issue with this  Q on Latency area. When we are having high load in application via this MQ, Latency comes and data is not getting painted in UI. This is an intermittent issue , but we want to know is it related to latency or some other MQ tuning will resolve or not? what kind of trace we can enable for  "Default messaging provider" and other other tuning to resolve latency?

```
17-May-2021
```

**WebSphere Console to get Depth Set and used Depth ["Default messaging provider"]**

**--current depth set Queue["Default messaging provider"] ---**

Security > Bus Security > *Bus > Messaging engines > cluster1.001-*Bus > Queue points > *****Queue@cluster1.001-*Bus>>"High message threshold "

**--current Queue["Default messaging provider"] depth on peak time---**

Security > Bus Security > *Bus > Messaging engines > cluster1.001-*Bus > Queue points

Comment: @chughts is the "Default messaging provider" the OP is asking about considered IBM MQ?  Also does WebSphere 9 =  WebSphere Liberty?

Comment: Since 8.5 WebSphere could be mean Liberty profile, but the question isn't explicit. I added the tag to open up visibility of the question to those who know how to tune the default messaging provider.

Comment: @JoshMc - I think "Default messaging provider" is not IBM MQ. It is the other Java-based messaging provided shipped with WAS. Forget it's official name. To me this question reads as though there is no IBM MQ part to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Latency can be caused by applications being too slow to process the work.
This in turn can be caused by applications taking too long to process the transaction eg quick MQ request, and long SQL request followed by commit.
Or it could be caused by not enough threads processing the work.
As a first step increase the number of transactions processing the work.

Comment: for Topic....will get error like "is not available because the high limit 50,000 for the number of messages for this destination has already been reached..; "..for Q also  "Default messaging provider" ..will get similar message on reached bottleneck?

Comment: com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.exceptions.SIMPLimitExceededException: will give depth related for Q and Topic

Comment: These statements are true, and are a symptom of work not being processed.   They do not cause Latency.  If you get these exceptions you need to find why the queue is not being processed.

Comment: I am not getting SIMPLimitExceededException in error logs , but all are pointing to latency and i dont have any answer to trace latency in  "Default messaging provider" Q., also to find depth of  "Default messaging provider" Q.